# Match numbers after first character

Tags: regex

I'd like to use Regex to determine whether the characters after the first are all numbers.

For example:

- A123 would be valid as after A there are only numbers
- A12B would be invalid as, after the first character, there is another letter

I essentially want to ignore the first character

I have so far this:

```
(?<=A)\w*(?=)
```

but this makes A12B or A1B2C valid, I only want numbers after A.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: [`^[A-Z]\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NwXt0z/1)

Comment: @cl0ud Updated it, mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match not a digit `\D`, followed by matching 1+ times a digit. If that is the whole string, you could use anchors asserting the start `^` and the `$` end of the string.

```
^\D\d+$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `\D` Match not a digit
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits making sure there are digits
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/caczXX/1/)

Comment: @Jan You might be right, I was reading the positive lookbehind `(?<=A)` and thought that this should not be a digit.

Comment: I agree, this can go multiple ways `characters after the first are all numbers` vs `only want numbers after A` vs `match numbers after first character`

Comment: found a problem - `_445` as an example , won't work for special char @ first letter I guess.

Comment: I mean to say, the question (this post) has asked for first one as letter. Which won't work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @smilyface I think that has not been very clear reading the question. See the second comment above.

Comment: Hmm. You must be right. Actual requirement would be different sometimes. Questionnaire might miss these kind of things while asking. Anyway your answer or my answer will surely help others !!

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is very complicated, especially given how simple is your goal.
Succeeding at regexes is all about simplicity.

The first character can be anything, so just go with `.`.
The next ones are all digits, so you want `\d`.
You'll star it to specify restriction-less repetition, or use `+` if you want at least one.

Finally, you need to anchor your regex at the beginning and at the end, else it would match stuff like `A123XXXXX` or `XXXXA123`.
Note that most implementations of `match` will already anchor the pattern at the end, so you can omit the caret at the beginning.

Final regex:

```
^.\d*$
```

Comment: the question is about the whole sequence, "the first character". Your regex also matches on (a part of) A342B345C123. in this case C123, 123, 23 and 3.

Comment: @Chrᴉz Most sane matching functions anchor the pattern at the start, but if you want...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is:

```
^.\d*$
```

- `^` - Start of the line
- `.` - Any character (except line terminators)
- `\d*`

  - `\d`- a number
  - `*` - repeated any number of times (including 0 times. If you want it to be at least 1, change it to `+`).
- `$` - End of the line

```js
let regex = /^.\d*$/;

let testStrings = ['A123', 'A12B'];

testStrings.forEach(str => {
  console.log(`${str} is ${regex.test(str) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$

1. `^` - "starting with" (Here it is starting with any letter). Read it as `^[a-zA-Z]`
2. `[a-z]` - any small letters and `A-Z` any capital letters (you may change if required.)
3. `[0-9]` - any numbers
4. `{3}` - describes how many numbers you want to check. You have to read it as `[0-9]{3}`
5. `$` - End of the statement. (Means, in this case it will end up with 3 numbers)

Here you can play around - https://regex101.com/r/mqUHvP/5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
(?<=.{1,1})([0-9]+)(?=\s)
```

(?<=.{1,1}) - has exactly one character before

([0-9]+) - at least one digit

(?=\s) - has a whitespace after

Add `^` at the beginning - to specify beginning of line

Replace `(?=\s)` with `$` for end of line